# Sledgehammer within Locale

Tags: isabelle

I am a happy user of Isabelle/Isar and Sledgehammer, but am just now trying to also use locales, as in my use case there are just overwhelming arguments for it.

I am using the Isabelle/December 2021 distribution, but most of the time when I am trying to use sledgehammer within a locale context, I will get a message like this:

```
"cvc4": Prover error:
exception TERM raised (line 457 of "~~/src/HOL/Tools/SMT/smt_translate.ML"): bad SMT term
```

It is the same message for other provers as well. Is this something that is a well-known problem? Without using locales I had such a problem only come up when my theory name was confused with some HOL theory name, and renaming my theory was a workaround. Is there something similar at play here? Is there an easy fix? Because I use sledgehammer a lot, so not being able to use it within a locale would be a severe blow against using locales.

Comment: That works for me: `
locale test =
  fixes f :: \<open>'a \<Rightarrow> 'a\<close>
begin

definition g where \<open>g = map f\<close>
lemma \<open>g (xs @ ys) = g xs @ g ys\<close>
  sledgehammer[cvc4, debug]`

Comment: Ah I just saw that you also asked on the mailing list. Answering there with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, a summary of the discussion on the [Isabelle mailing-list](https://isabelle.systems/zulip-archive/stream/247541-Mirror:-Isabelle-Users-Mailing-List/topic/.5Bisabelle.5D.20Sledgehammer.20in.20Locale.20Context.3F.html).

There is an issue in the translation from Isabelle to SMT Lib (the language for SMT solvers): lets inside lets are not translated correctly. This should be fixed in the next Isabelle release.

The work-around in the mean time is to avoid let inside let.